# converting .pem keys to .der compiles but results in errors

Tags: ssl, rust

Calling my `hyper` based API now ported to HTTPS, with Python's `requests` I'm getting

`SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'` on every request.

As per the docs for `tokio_rustls`:

- `Certificate` has to be [DER-encoded X.509](https://docs.rs/rustls/latest/rustls/struct.Certificate.html)
- `PrivateKey` has to be [DER-encoded ASN.1 in either PKCS#8 or PKCS#1 format](https://docs.rs/rustls/latest/rustls/struct.PrivateKey.html).

The keys I used in my `PKEY` and `CERT` variables are my `certbot` generated `.pem` keys converted to `.der` format using those commands:

`openssl x509 -outform der -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/cert.pem -out /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/cert.der`

`openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem -out /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.der -nocrypt`

And loaded up with `include_bytes!()` macro.

Well it compiles, polls... and just throws this error on every request `Bad connection: cannot decrypt peer's message` whilst the caller gets the `SSLError` mentioned in the beginning.

Here is the script used for the API:

```
fn tls_acceptor_impl(cert_der: &[u8], key_der: &[u8]) -> tokio_rustls::TlsAcceptor {
    let key = PrivateKey(cert_der.into());
    let cert = Certificate(key_der.into());
    Arc::new(
        ServerConfig::builder()
            .with_safe_defaults()
            .with_no_client_auth()
            .with_single_cert(vec![cert], key)
            .unwrap(),
    )
    .into()
}

fn tls_acceptor() -> tokio_rustls::TlsAcceptor {
    tls_acceptor_impl(PKEY, CERT)
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>> {
    let addr = SocketAddr::from(...);
    let mut listener = tls_listener::builder(tls_acceptor())
        .max_handshakes(10)
        .listen(AddrIncoming::bind(&addr).unwrap());

    let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel::<tokio_rustls::TlsAcceptor>(1);

    let http = Http::new();
    loop {
        tokio::select! {
            conn = listener.accept() => {
                match conn.expect("Tls listener stream should be infinite") {
                    Ok(conn) => {
                        let http = http.clone();
                        // let tx = tx.clone();
                        // let counter = counter.clone();
                        tokio::spawn(async move {
                            // let svc = service_fn(move |request| handle_request(tx.clone(), counter.clone(), request));
                            if let Err(err) = http.serve_connection(conn, service_fn(my_query_handler)).await {
                                eprintln!("Application error: {}", err);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    Err(e) => {
                        eprintln!("Bad connection: {}", e);
                    }
                }
            },
            message = rx.recv() => {
                // Certificate is loaded on another task; we don't want to block the listener loop
                let acceptor = message.expect("Channel should not be closed");
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I make any sense of the errors, when the certificate keys work on Web (as they are the `apache2` server's keys)? I've tried various other encodings, that are against the docs, and all fail in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with rust, but I know that proper configuration of a TLS server (no matter which language) requires the server certificate, the key matching the certificate and *all intermediate CA needed to build the trust chain from server certificate to the root CA on the clients machine*. These intermediate CA are not provided in your code. That's why the Python code fails to validate the certificate.

What you need is probably something like this:

```
     ServerConfig::builder()
        ....
        .with_single_cert(vec![cert, intermediate_cert], key)
```

Where `intermediate_cert` is the internal representation of the *Let’s Encrypt R3* CA, which you can find [here](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/#intermediate-certificates).

Comment: @tommy1213: *"getting error "hostname 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' doesn't match 'mysite.com'"."* - this error is different than what you get before. It now no longer fails to validate the trust chain ("unable to get local issuer certificate"), so my answer seems to work. The new error is caused by the certificate not being valid for the domain name(s) you use to access it:   if the certificate is issued for foo.example.com it will fail with the error you see when you access the server with bar.example.com or with IP address.

Comment: I had to change links from `https://ip/ `to `https://domain.name/ `and this resolved the issue